# Getting different hierarchical clustering in ComplexHeatmap for the same method of performing clustering

Tags: r, complexheatmap

I'm using the following code to get a [ComplexHeatmap](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/) in R. I tried two different methods, specified in the comments in the code. The only difference between the two is that in the first one, I rely on the ComplexHeatmap to do the clustering, while in the second case, I do the clustering myself, and pass the hclust object to Heatmap. In theory, I should be getting the same clustering for the data, but I'm not. I'm not sure what I'm misunderstanding. I know the heatmaps should not be the same, but I believe the clustering of the samples should be. I've shared the data in [this](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/1123) Github post about this.
PS: The clustering is similar (but displayed in reversed order), but not the exact same.

```
lung = read.csv("all_lung.csv")
lung["subtype_grouped_meso"] = lung["subtype"]
lung[lung["subtype"] == "Not.Otherwise.Specified" | lung["subtype"] == 
       "Epithelioid" | lung["subtype"] == "Sarcomatoid" | 
       lung["subtype"] == "Biphasic", 
     "subtype_grouped_meso"] = "meso"
subtype = lung[["subtype_grouped_meso"]]
rownames(lung) = lung[["X"]]
lung = lung[, chr_keep]

subtype_colors <- c(
  "Adeno" = "red",
  "Squamous" = "green",
  "SCLC" = "blue",
  "meso" = "orange"
)

lung = t(lung)
column_ha <- HeatmapAnnotation(subtype = subtype, 
                               counts = log10(colSums(lung)),
                               col = list(subtype = 
                                            subtype_colors))

# Method 1
Heatmap(lung,
        top_annotation = column_ha,
        clustering_distance_columns = "pearson",
        clustering_method_columns = "ward.D",
        cluster_rows = F,
        show_column_names = F,
        show_row_names = F, 
        show_row_dend = F)

# Method 2 (manually do the clustering) 
cor_matrix <- cor(lung, method = "pearson")
cor_distance <- as.dist(1 - cor_matrix)
hc <- hclust(cor_distance, method = "ward.D")
Heatmap(cor_matrix, 
        top_annotation = column_ha,
        name = "correlation",
        cluster_columns = hc,
        cluster_rows = hc,
        show_column_names = F,
        show_row_names = F,
        show_row_dend = F,
        col = colorRamp2(c(-1, 0, 1), c("blue", "white", "red")))
```

Comment: It is a poor assumption that different clustering techniques will yield identical clusters.  Not all methods are deterministic and could yield different clusters on each run.  Different methods will used different methods to calculate distances and center point locations.  So it is not surprising that you have similar but not identical heat maps.

Comment: @Dave2e but 1) it's the same clustering technique (hierarchical clustering with 1-pearson correlation for distance and ward for linkage) and 2) hierarchical clustering is supposed to be deterministic

Comment: @Dave2e also, again the heatmaps I'm not expecting to be the same, but the clustering should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829127/inconsistent-clustering-with-complexheatmap). The punchline is best described by the `reorder.dendogram` function from the `stats` package:

> There are many different orderings of a dendrogram that are consistent with the structure imposed. This function takes a dendrogram and a vector of values and reorders the dendrogram in the order of the supplied vector, maintaining the constraints on the dendrogram.